# Strange text reading from file using fread

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, fwrite, fread

Im having problems with the read from a file I write to, it shows strange tokens and not the text I tried to print. It's probably just a simple solution but I can't find it. Been sitting here for hours now! :/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wggkg.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "allafunktioner.h"

struct vinnare{
    int ar;
    char namn[20];
};
struct vinnare *inlasningTillFil(struct vinnare *vinnare, int antalvinnareinlasning);
int meny();

int vinnarear(int ar, char namnlista, int vinnare);
void artistnamn(int ar, char namnlista, int vinnare);
void skrivutalla(int ar, int  namnlista, int vinnare);

main(){
    int a=1, val, antalvinnareinlasning,test=0;

    struct vinnare *vinnare;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("F:\\Uppgifter", "rb");

    if (file == NULL){

        vinnare = NULL;
        printf("Ange antal vinnare:");
        scanf("%d", &antalvinnareinlasning);
        vinnare = (struct vinnare *)malloc(antalvinnareinlasning*sizeof(struct vinnare));
        vinnare = inlasningTillFil(vinnare, antalvinnareinlasning);
    }
    else{

        fread(&antalvinnareinlasning, sizeof(int), 1, file);
        printf("%d", antalvinnareinlasning);
        vinnare =(struct vinnare *)malloc(antalvinnareinlasning*sizeof(struct vinnare));

        for (a = 1; a < (antalvinnareinlasning + 1); a++){
            fread(&vinnare[a].ar, sizeof(int), 1, file);
            fread(&vinnare[a].namn, sizeof(char)*20, 1, file);
            printf("%d", vinnare[a].ar);
            printf("%s", vinnare[a].namn);
        }


    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}


struct vinnare *inlasningTillFil(struct vinnare *vinnare, int antalvinnareinlasning){
    int a, temp;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("F:\\Uppgifter", "wb");

    vinnare[0].ar = antalvinnareinlasning;


    fwrite(&vinnare[0], sizeof(struct vinnare),1, file);


    for (a = 1; a < (antalvinnareinlasning + 1); a++){
        printf("Ange vilket år du vill mata in: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        vinnare[a].ar = temp;
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Ange vinnaren för det året:");
        fgets(vinnare[a].namn, 20, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);

        fwrite(&vinnare[a], sizeof(struct vinnare), 1, file);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `struct vinnare`?  Are you opening the file for reading in binary mode (`"rb"`)?

Comment: Post a complete, compilable program, and some sample input and incorrect output.

Comment: Now I added whole code and picture :)

Answer (score 1):

When you first read the file in, you read an `int` for the number of records.

```
fread(&antalvinnareinlasning, sizeof(int), 1, file);
```

But when you write the file the first thing you do is write an uninitialized `struct vinnare`:

```
fwrite(&vinnare[0], sizeof(struct vinnare),1, file);
```

So your file format doesn't line up and you end up with binary data from `int` in your `char` field.

Also, I would recommend that you do your `fread` exactly the same as your `fwrite` in case there is padding in your structure.  `sizeof(struct vinnare)` in not guarenteeded to be exactly the same as `sizeof(int) + sizeof(char[20])`, therefore:

```
fread(&vinnare[a].ar, sizeof(int), 1, file);
fread(&vinnare[a].namn, sizeof(char)*20, 1, file);
```

is not that same necessarily as

```
fread( &( vinnare[a]), sizeof(struct vinnare), 1, file) ;
```

Finally, you allocate `N` records in memory to store the `struct`, but you use the wrong ones.  You need to index `0` through `N-1` not `1` to `N` in your `for` loop in `inlasningTillFil`.  The last one read will be at location `&vinnare[N]` which is not valid.

Comment: ALMOST!!! :D It still writes the same numbers in the beggining. Changed all the sizeof to sizeof(struct vinnare). So close now!! :)

Comment: Didnt make a difference, the problem is that it's working if I only have two structs, the first one telling how many structs there is in the file (a must for my task), but as soon as I have more than 2 it shows the first year and then the name breaks up :/ 

http://imgur.com/ANTCSAZ

Comment: Fix the indexing on `vinnare`.  In C indexes start with `0`.

Comment: Yes, but given that the first byte should be just for telling how many there is in the file I dont want to write over it. Sorry, forgott to tell about that :/